# Linq and DisplayFor in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I've got a model that has an `ICollection` of telephone numbers. In my view I want to display the value for the record that is marked as Primary.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephones.Where(a=>a.Primary==true).Number)
```

The `.Number` is not allowed in the Linq syntax. How would one go about making the above line work or rather what is the proper way to display the number?

I probably should do the logic in the controller and put the value in a view model but it seems like this should be doable.

Comment: I feel its better to have a readonly property called PrimaryNumber inside which you can do the linq operation to fetch the Number. Then bind the displayfor to that number property.

Comment: Why do you feel this way?

Comment: I felt that way because the model logic should reside in Model layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. If you just want the first item which satisfies the condition, use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535050%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephones.First(a => a.Primary).Number)
```

If you also need to ensure that *exactly one* item in the set satisfies the condition (and throw an exception otherwise), consider using [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Telephones.Single(a => a.Primary).Number)
```

Comment: Should be mindful of case if no number is found.  I believe in that case `First` returns null which will cause NullRef exception.  Need to handle that case.

Comment: @LB2 You're thinking of `FirstOrDefault`. `First` will raise an `InvalidOperationException` if it can't find at least one element which satisfies the condition.

Comment: Also, be aware that if you're using .Single, you will actually issue a Top 2 vs First which does Top 1. The only reason to use Single is if you need the exception to be thrown if more than one exists.